# How to specify filesize of Hive EXTERNAL TABLE data on S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I can create an `EXTERNAL TABLE` in Hive where the data is stored in an S3 bucket in Gzip format. However, the files are very large (over 6GB each).

Can Hive be configured to make files in an `EXTERNAL TABLE` a specific size, say, 512MB?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds weird to me, by default, my external tables usually have a file size of around 300MB. Anyway The easiest way to tune this is to use a `PARTITION BY` key, (something base on timestamp probably), which will force the files to be smaller, and will have the added advantage of making your data easier to query. Also you should consider using a splittable format like Parquet, since then it won't really matter what your file size is.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is not uniformly distributed across a partitionable key. Also I'm using Hive as a step in an ETL so the query performance is not as important as throughput of data overall. The large file size is causing a bottleneck at other points in the ETL.